# What do they utilize to build android apps with custom graphics and controls ?

Tags: android, graphics, controllers

What I mean to say while you're just getting started with the development and say you add a slider theres a predefined skin for that and you can place it somewhere on the screen, but in some apps there are things like a knob in a place of slider which you can rotate to do the same stuff what the slider does . How do they do that, does it require openGL or something I am not asking for a complete tutorial or something just curious on what stuff goes into building such thing

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, if something is not provided out of the box, you will have to build your own control.

For example, you mention a *Knob*. That isn't available in the Android SDK. Such a control could prove to be useful.

Here is a tutorial to build such a custom Control: http://go-lambda.blogspot.in/2012/02/rotary-knob-widget-on-android.html

*This is an image of the final result from the tutorial linked above:*

[image]

Here is an example of a custom slider / seek bar: http://permadi.com/blog/2011/11/android-sdk-custom-slider-bar-seekbar/

This should give you a rough idea on how to go about creating your own custom views.

<strike>And finally, what I personally find the best possible resource for keeping track of *almost* all good Custom Views is here: http://www.androidviews.net/</strike>

The androidviews.net website has shut down. [Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/) is a *new* website that lists several third party Android libraries.

Comment: That's like the best website I have visited in a while Thanks

Comment: @nashmaniac: I know right.. I find it indispensable at times. :-)

Comment: @IceMAN the site is down. Do You know where it has moved?

Comment: @jeand'arme: Thank for bringing it to my attention. I have updated the post. :-)